# How do I animate the inner views of a collection view cell while changing it's size?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a collection view, and I'm going for the effect where when a cell is tapped on, it grows to take up the entire screen.  To accomplish this, I'm essentially just calling `performBatchUpdates` inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, and the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` knows to return a larger size for a selected cell.  This all works pretty well, the cell grows and shrinks as desired.

The problem is inside of the cell.  The collection view cell is made up of a moderately complex view hierarchy managed by constraints.  I want the sub views of the cell to grow and shrink with the animating cell.  Unfortunately, my subviews are snapping immediately to their new position as the cell slowly animates to it's new size.  How can I ensure the content of the cell animates with the cell size?

Here are the two relevant methods from the collection view controller:

```
- (CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems containsObject:indexPath])
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width - 20, collectionView.bounds.size.height - (20 + [self.topLayoutGuide length]));
else
    return CGSizeMake(260, 100); 
}

- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Your subviews are snapping into place most likely because some flag that denotes the cell being expanded switches from false to true, and then `layoutSubviews` gets called, which immediately moves the subviews to their expanded positions. I'm just guessing though - if you add code we'll be able to see if that's the case. On another note - should the cell expand over the top of the other cells in the collection, or should it push them out of the way? If it should expand over the top, I recommend adding a new view above the UICollectionView and animating that.

Comment: I added the two relevant methods that do the resizing on selection.  There's very little other code in the view controller.  The cell itself is a few nib files, nothing that I can easily add to the post.

Answer (score 11):

I had exactly the same problem. After many tries, the following code did the trick for me. Calling layoutIfNeed directly after the batch update with a duration of 3.0 (+- the batchupdate duration) animated the constraints.

```
[self performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];

// IndexPath of cell to be expanded
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: yes, this does work, I used it solved the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I would like to expand on Antoine's answer. Calling `performBatchUpdates:completion:` inside the animation block will actually set the cell resize duration and match the content resize to it.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [self performBatchUpdates:^{
        // set flags needed for new cell size calculation
    } completion:nil];
    [collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

This way you can also play with the animation timing or even use spring animations.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Add these to your subclass of CollectionViewCell. It works for me.

```
// ProblematicCollectionViewCell.swift

override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    super.apply(layoutAttributes)
   layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Here is the origanl link : https://codedump.io/share/LXZwAOOMxafU/1/uicollectionviewcell---contents-do-not-animate-alongside-cell39s-contentview the answer is in the comments.